# ThreeBSP wrong result

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm having some troubles with a tube in Three.JS. I have to cut it at 45 degrees and then connect this tube with another one (a connection with "L" form).
My idea is this:
- I create a cube
- I change the position of the cube
- I use a substration between the tube and the cube to get the result

I found that the "subtract" function gives to me a strange result.

Here there is the simplified code (here the cube is not rotated but I will need to rotate it to get my result) and the image the with the undesired result (inside the yellow rectangle).

```
var cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry(25, 25, 25);
var cMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cube);
cMesh.position.y=100;
cMesh.updateMatrix();

var path = new THREE.LineCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(0, 100, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0,-100, 0));
var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(path, 20, 2, 18, false);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

var geom1 = new ThreeBSP(mesh);
var geom2=new ThreeBSP(cMesh);
var geomF=geom1.subtract(geom2);
mesh = geomF.toMesh();
```

[problem detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGgiT.png)

Comment: Why do you have **java** tag here?

Comment: why not to use `THREE.CylinderGeometry()` with default value of the `.openEnded` property (`false`) instead of `THREE.TubeGeometry()`?

Comment: Wxcuse me for the wrong tag.

Comment: the prisoner849 solution works!!!! thank you!